# Proofs of Network Data

Tags: network

Would like to have some hints on solving the following proofs related to network data.

1. Let $z_{m}$ be the average number of neighbours at distance $m$ from a randomly selected node in a network $G_{n}$ with $n$ nodes. By considering the degree distribution of a node reached by following a randomly chosen edge, show that the following recurrence relationship holds.

$$z_{m} = \bigg( \dfrac{E(k^{2}) - E(k)}{E(k)}\bigg) z_{m-1}, m > 1 \text{ and } z_{1} = E(k),$$

where $k$ is a random variable of the degree of a randomly selected node in the network.

2. The diameter $\ell$ of the network can be estimated when the total number of neighbours of a randomly selected node at distance $\leq \ell$ equals the number of nodes in the network. Using this argument, show that

$$\ell = 1+\dfrac{\log(n/z_{1})}{\log(z_{2}/z{1})}.$$

3. When a fraction $f$ of nodes and their corresponding edges in the network are randomly removed, the degree distribution is changed from $p_{k}$ to $p_{k'}$, where

$$p_{k'} = \sum_{k=k'}^{\infty} p_{k} \begin{bmatrix} k\\k'\end{bmatrix} f^{k-k'} (1-f)^{k'}.$$

Show that the first and second moment of the new degree distribution become

$$
\begin{aligned}
E(k') &= (1-f)E(k) \\
E(k'^{2}) &= (1-f)^{2}E(k^{2}) + f(1-f)E(k).
\end{aligned}
$$

Using Molloy-Reed criterion, show that the network dismantles when $f > f_{c}$, where

$$f_{c} = 1 - \dfrac{E(k)}{E(k^{2}) - E(k)}.$$

4. Suppose that $p_{k} \propto k^{-\gamma}, \gamma > 0$. Let $k_{min}$ and $k_{max}$ be the observed minimum degree and the observed maximum degree respectively. Find $f_{c}$ in terms of $\gamma$, $k_{min}$ and $k_{max}$. Demonstrate that, when $2 < \gamma < 3$, $f_{c}$ tends to one and, when $\gamma > 3$, $f_{c}$ is a constant independent of the network size. Furthermore, argue that we cannot dismantle a scale-free network by random removel of nodes when $2 < \gamma < 3$.

Comment: What have you tried? We can't help you if we don't know where you're stuck.

Comment: I have no clue on how to start working on all these...

Comment: Could anyone help with the second question? I guess I got the other three...